# Jdbc Question : getting connection method working?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have loaded both Oracle and MySQL drivers.

Which database connection will be established when I call the `getConnection()` method?

Comment: What is your configuration?

Comment: Depends on the database connection URL "jdbc:mysql:..." is for an MySQL connection, "jdbc/ora..." for an Oracle one.

Comment: What `getConnection()` method? On what class or object? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

When you call `DriverManager.getConnection()` the driver manager iterates through all registered JDBC drivers and asks each driver if it is capable of connecting with the supplied URL (with modern Java and driver versions, this driver registrations happens automatically, alternatively  this is what the outdated `Class.forName()` also results in)

The first driver that says "Yes, I can do that" will then be used to establish the connection.

As the JDBC URL contains distinct prefixes for each DBMS systems, there is no ambiguity here. An URL starting with `jdbc:oracle:` will be handled by the Oracle driver, an URL starting with `jdbc:mysql:` will be handled by the MySQL driver, `jdbc:postgresql` will be handled by the Postgres driver.

---

Different drivers for the same DBMS usually use different URL syntax, so they can be distinguished as well. E.g. the Microsoft JDBC driver uses `jdbc:sqlserver:` whereas the jTDS driver uses `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:`

Comment: Are you sure the OP is asking about one of the `DriverManager.getConnection` methods, and not for example some `DataSource.getConnection()` call?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: no I am not sure. But it seemed like a reasonable assumption given the fact that he "loads" the drivers manually (which would not be the case with two distinct datasources)

Answer (score 0):

Vinit

It depends on which one is referenced on the URL connection that you are using where you are getting the connection. If you are using an URL connection like `jdbc:mysql://`, is your MySQL that is being used or, if you are using an URL connection like `jdbc:oracle:`, is your Oracle that is being used.

Comment: Are you sure the OP is asking about one of the `DriverManager.getConnection` methods, and not for example some `DataSource.getConnection()` call?